# C# Regex: Capture text between specific words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex to make the following extractions (text after **tag/** and **page/**):

- /prefix/tag/`abc`/page/`15`
- /prefix/tag/`abc`
- /prefix/page/`15`

So, basically, I need a pattern which will capture 2 groups for each from above strings. 
The results should be:

- for the first string:  $1=abc and $2=15
- for the second string: $1=abc and $2=empty
- for the third string: $1=empty and $2=15

The `/prefix/(?:tag)/([^/]+)/(?:page)/([^/]+)` pattern does exactly what I need, but just for the first string. It would be great if this can be modified so that it would return the needed results for the second and the third strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe [`/(?:tag|page)/(?<res>[^/]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f(%3f%3atag%7cpage)%2f(%3f%3cres%3e%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b)&i=%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%2fpage%2f15%0d%0a%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%0d%0a%2fprefix%2fpage%2f15)?

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor for your quick and good comment.
I use this at a url rewrite engine, and due to this I also need the pattern to contain "/prefix/" text.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the context. Are you trying to rewrite the values in the first bullet points into the second bullet points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex that can help you is

```
/(prefix)/(?:tag|page)/([^/]+)
```

The [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f(prefix)%2f(%3f%3atag%7cpage)%2f(%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b)&i=%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%2fpage%2f15%0d%0a%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%0d%0a%2fprefix%2fpage%2f15) is here.

[image]

Basically, the regex matches a `/` followed with `prefix` (captured into Group 1) followed with `/` and then either `tag` or `page` followed with another `/`, and then the regex engine tries to capture into Group 2 one or more characters other than `/`.

**UPDATE**:

For the issue discussed in the comments try the following pattern ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d%5cS)(%3f%3a(%3f%3a%2f(abc))(%3f%3a%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b)*%3f)%3f(%3f%3a%2f(%5cd%2b))%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%2fpage%2f15%0d%0a%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%0d%0a%2fprefix%2fpage%2f15&o=m)):

```
(?=\S)(?:(?:/(abc))(?:/[^/]+)*?)?(?:/(\d+))?$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! Is it possible to get the 2 results in 2 numbered captures as $1 and $2? I would also need to use the **/prefix/** inside the pattern.

Comment: You mean you want to capture the literal word `prefix` that should be Group 1? Like [`/(prefix)/(?:tag|page)/([^/]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f(prefix)%2f(%3f%3atag%7cpage)%2f(%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b)&i=%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%2fpage%2f15%0d%0a%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%0d%0a%2fprefix%2fpage%2f15)? (See *Table* section at the bottom of the page at regexstorm.net)

Comment: I need a pattern which will capture the following results:
- /prefix/tag/abc/page/15 $1=abc and $2=15

- /prefix/tag/abc $1=abc  and $2=empty

- /prefix/page/15 $1=empty and $2=15

The `/prefix/(?:tag)/([^/]+)/(?:page)/([^/]+)` pattern does exactly what I need, but just for the first string. It would be great if this can be modified so that it would return the needed results for the second and the third strings. Thank again, Wiktor!

Comment: Try [`(?=\S)(?:(?:/(abc))(?:/[^/]+)*?)?(?:/(\d+))?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d%5cS)(%3f%3a(%3f%3a%2f(abc))(%3f%3a%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b)*%3f)%3f(%3f%3a%2f(%5cd%2b))%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%2fpage%2f15%0d%0a%2fprefix%2ftag%2fabc%0d%0a%2fprefix%2fpage%2f15&o=m).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
var folders = myValue.Split('/');
var matches = folders.Skip(1)
    .Where((f, i) => folders[i] == "tag" || folders[i] == "page");
```

Easier to read and likely more efficient than using regex.

Comment: That's a bit tricky - it does what is expected, but my first impression was that it extracts the parts that *are* 'tag' and 'page'...   if this code was in production I would hope that it included comments that clarify what it really does.

Comment: @MichaelBray Yeah, a `for` clause would probably have been more readable, but this is slightly shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuriy, but I need this for an url rewrite engine which forces me to use regex.

Comment: @user3684328 usually Url Rewrite engines allow for methods as well.

Comment: Yes, but this is a custom engine made by somebody else and I wouldn't make changes there. Thanks.